# How uploaded file on Firebase storage then store the url inside firestore with vue 3 (composition API)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

im new to firebase and vue 3 and i have prob dealing with upload to storage, i am uploading the file (image) on firebase and want to store it to firestore with all other data from inputs, i was able to save all data from form but cant with the file url, im using this fucntion :

```
<input @change="uploadTaskPromise" class="file-input" type="file" name="file">
```

```
import { getStorage, ref as stRef, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";



const uploadTaskPromise = (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const storage = getStorage();

  const metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
};
  
  const storageRef = stRef(storage, 'products/' + file.name);

  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata);

  
uploadTask.on('state_changed',
  (snapshot) => {
    
    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case 'paused':
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case 'running':
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, 
  (error) => {
    
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'storage/unauthorized':
        
        break;
      case 'storage/canceled':
        
        break;

      // ...

      case 'storage/unknown':
        
        break;
    }
  }, 
  () => {
    
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {


      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);

      resolve({ imgUrl: downloadURL });
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - i've made a simple form ...

```
<template>
  <form action="#" @submit.prevent>
    <div>
      <label for="title">Product title</label>
      <input v-model="title" type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="price">Product price</label>
      <input v-model="price" type="number" id="price" min="0" placeholder="0.00" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="file">Product photo</label>
      <input @change="handleFileChange" type="file" id="file" />
    </div>

    <button @click="submitForm">Send</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

... and connected it with script

```
<script>
// this variables setup-ed in config.js
import { storage, productsCollectionRef } from '../firebase/config'
// this function from firebase. need to upload file
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage'
// this one for creating document in database (firestore) 
import { addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'

export default {
  // child component, imported in main App.vue
  name: 'vue-upload',
  data() {
    return {
      title: null,
      price: 0,
      file: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleFileChange(e) {
      // when file selected - update property in data()
      this.file = e.target.files[0]
    },

    createProduct(data) {
      // pass a reference to collection and data
      addDoc(productsCollectionRef, data)
    },

    uploadFile(file) {
      // getting name & type properties from File object
      const { name, type } = file
      // create a reference to file in firebase
      const storageRef = ref(storage, 'images/' + name)
      // upload file (this.file) to firebase and append metadata
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, this.file, {
        contentType: type
      })

      uploadTask.on(
        'state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done')
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        },
        () => {
          // successful upload. get url ...
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            // ... make a data to write ...
            const data = {
              title: this.title,
              price: this.price,
              url: downloadURL
            }
            // ... and call a fn that writes a document to a firestore
            this.createProduct(data)
          })
        }
      )
    },

    submitForm() {
      // just quick & simple validation
      if (this.title && this.price && this.file) {
        this.uploadFile(this.file)
        return
      }

      alert('Form invalid')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You may notice a `import { storage, productsCollectionRef } from '../firebase/config'` line.
It's just another one js-file, where i pass configuration for firebase:

*./firebase/config.js*

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'

import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage'
import { getFirestore, collection } from 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'XXXXX',
  authDomain: 'XXXXX',
  projectId: 'XXXXX',
  storageBucket: 'XXXXX',
  messagingSenderId: 'XXXXX',
  appId: 'XXXXX'
}

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const storage = getStorage(app)
const db = getFirestore(app)

// i've made a 'products' collection in my firestore database [screenshot][1]
const productsCollectionRef = collection(db, 'products')
// we need export this setuped variables for use in another file
export { storage, productsCollectionRef }
```

Comment: thank you Bohdan for your help, it works like charm, i have one more question if possible, what if we want upload multiple files, this code will still work the same ?

Comment: @bahyllam need to add few changes. 1. add a `multiple` attribute to your input filed 2. in `handleFileChange` fn - save all selected files (in array for example) 3. in `uploadFile` fn you need to loop through your array and wait till all files upload, then return all urls (also in array for exapmple) and finally - call a `createProduct` with this data.

Answer (score 0):

@bahyllam i don't have enough reputation to add a comment.

in your previous code (Apr 10 at 5:05), you have an array in `this.files`, but your `uploadFile(file)` function takes a single `file` as an argument.
So inside this function you need to make a loop for the whole array and call all the code for each `file` separately (get a `name` & `type` for each file, make `storageRef` and `uploadTask`. BUT only once make a write operation:

```
handleFileChange(e) {
    if (e.target.files) {
        for (const file of e.target.files) {
            this.files.push(file)
        }
    }
}

uploadFile() {
  const urls = []
  const promises = []

  this.files.forEach((file) => {
    // getting name & type properties from each File object
    const { name, type } = file
    // create a reference to each file in firebase
    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'images/' + name)
    // upload each file to firebase and append metadata
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, {
      contentType: type
    })

    // create task with promises. this will help us to expect the result correctly
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      uploadTask.on(
        'state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done')
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
          reject(error)
        },
        async () => {
          // wait for URL from getDownloadURL 
          const url = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
          urls.push(url)
          resolve(url)
        }
      )
    })

    // add task to "waitlist"
    promises.push(promise)
  })

  // when all "waitlist" resolve ...
  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    // ... make a data to write ...
    const data = {
      title: this.title,
      price: this.price,
      // url: [Array]
      url: urls
    }
    // ... and call a fn that writes a document to a firestore
    this.createProduct(data)
  })
}
```